# Whenever string value is converted it is being changed to 1 - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, integer

I am having trouble converting a string value into a num value. It seems to only be a problem with $rows variable because I have tried storing an integer in a string like: $s="2" and was able to convert that to the correct integer no problem.

```
       //Where email input is being grabbed           
       $sanemail=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']); 

       //User_id is being grabbed
       $sql8="SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='".$sanemail."'";
       $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql8);
       $rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       $user_id=(int)$rows;
       var_dump($rows);
       var_dump($user_id);
```

var_dump($rows) returns "2" and for some reason var_dump($user_id) is returning 1. This seems to happen even if $rows= "3" 
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Why are you converting an array [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to an int? just wondering.  Try `$user_id=(int)$rows['user_id'];`  AND please pay attention to what others have said ^above^ they are all great comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an array for the results from the query. The explanation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). When you try to convert the array into an int, it will have undefined results as shown in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). Essentially, it will return a 1 because the array is not empty.

Change the line:
`$user_id=(int)$rows;`
to `$user_id=(int)$rows['user_id'];` to get the integer value instead of an array